# Floating point operations in linux kernel module (again)

Tags: linux-kernel, floating-point, fpu

I searched a lot of other questions inside StackOverflow, but none of them really solved my problem.

I am writing a linux kernel module and I need to compute a percentage value by diving an integer number by another integer number in order to get a float value ranging between 0 and 100:

```
int v1 = 5;
int v2 = 25;
float perc = v1 / v2;
```

For all the reasons we already know, when I try to compile it I get the "**SSE register return with SSE disabled**" error.

Is there a workaround to compute such division inside a Linux Kernel Module?

Thank you so much.
Antonio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use integer arithmetic, e.g.

```
int perc = 100 * v1 / v2;
```

This will give an integer percentage. If you need higher resolution than 1% then use a scale factor larger than 100 and insert a decimal point for display purposes as required.

Comment: +1 The right way to do floating point in the kernel is to not do it. OP: Is there a reason why you must do this in floating point?

Comment: FOP is not a must, the workaround provided @Paul solved the problem.

Comment: Just in case someone has not yet googled why floating point operations are not allowed in kernel space, here is a mailing list thread which tries to explain it. http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg30262.html